# caching smarty values but not the modifier output

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I have caching enabled in my smarty and have assigned a date and time as below that will only be fetched from database if the page is not cached:

```
$smarty->assign('added_timestamp', $added_timestamp);
```

I have a custom smarty modifier that generate a relative period like (20 minutes 5 seconds ago)

```
{$added_timestamp|relative_time}
```

now what I need is, the value for '$added_timestamp' must be cached however the output from `{$added_timestamp|relative_time}` should not be cached.

I tried with `{nocache}{$added_timestamp|relative_time}{/nocache}` but it doesn't work.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to wrap your relative_time modifier in a function plugin. that function plugin can be registered with the nocache flag (modifiers can't).

```
$smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'relative_time' 'smarty_function_relative_time', false, array('time'));
function smarty_function_relative_time(array $params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template) {
  $template->smarty->loadPlugin('smarty_modifier_relative_time');
  return smarty_modifier_relative_time($params[time]);
}
```

and

```
{relative_time time=$added_timestamp}
```

(Smarty3 syntax)